# ScrollView not scrollable

Tags: react-native

I have tried finding a solution everywhere but I couldn't find one for my problem. It's a basic example of ScrollView but it doesn't seem to work however I code it. See code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, Dimensions, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const LevelCircle = () => {  
 return (
 <View style={{height: 500}}>
       <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}> 
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          This is a ScrollView example HEADER.
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            This is a ScrollView example paragraph.
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            This is a ScrollView example paragraph.
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            This is a ScrollView example paragraph.
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            This is a ScrollView example paragraph.
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
            This is a ScrollView example paragraph.
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          This is a ScrollView example next.
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          This is a ScrollView example next.
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>
          This is a ScrollView example next.
        </Text>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});

export default LevelCircle;
```

I tried to set contentContainerStyle to flex: 1, and the solution with the padding, but it doesn't seem to work.
Also, I tried to set the parent View component style to flex: 1, but then it doesn't show the content inside it.

Answer (score 2):

`flexGrow: 1` should not be required as the height of the `<ScrollView>` is bounded by its parent element's fixed height.

When I run your code I see the intended behavior (a 500px bounded scrollView).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, I deleted the contentContainerStyle and it shows exactly like your pic but without the scrollbar and it doesn't scroll. What can be the problem?

Comment: I am on Android by the way.

Comment: Running on an android emulator on expo, I'm still seeing intended behavior (the scroll bar is only visible while scrolling, not when the component first loads. However, you can set `persistentScrollBar={true}` if you want it to show all the time.)

https://snack.expo.dev/@brendan5320/250170

Comment: I am seeing the project on expo go on my mobile, the issue is it is isn't scrollable at all